# How to use getlist() in django

Tags: django, django-views

as you can see in my views.py I have 3 loops and 3 getlist() but only one table use to save the data

```
for amount in request.POST.getlist('amount'):
  pass
for date in request.POST.getlist('date'):
  pass

for each in request.POST.getlist('remark'):
        insert_StudentPaymentSchedules = StudentPaymentSchedules(
                Students_Enrollment_Records =  V_insert_data,
                Amount = amount,
                Payment_Schedule = date,
                Remarks = each
            )
        insert_StudentPaymentSchedules.save()
```

this is the result

[image]

if you guys notice that the **remarks** are correct and the **Payment Schedule** and **Amount** is wrong, I have a problem for looping the 3 getlist()

models.py

```
class ScheduleOfPayment(models.Model):
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    Payment_Type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    Display_Sequence = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    Amount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    Remark = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True, null=True)

class StudentPaymentSchedules(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records=models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Payment_Schedule =models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    Amount = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Student_Payment_Date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    Paid_Amount = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Balance = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Remarks=models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
```

UPDATE full traceback

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are not processing `amount` and `date`, at all. There is no point traversing over them just to `pass`. Try this:

```
amounts = request.POST.getlist('amount')
dates = request.POST.getlist('date')
for i, remark in enumerate(request.POST.getlist('remark')):
    amount = amounts[i]
    date = dates[i]
    insert_StudentPaymentSchedules = StudentPaymentSchedules(
            Students_Enrollment_Records =  V_insert_data,
            Amount = amount,
            Payment_Schedule = date,
            Remarks = remark,
        )
    insert_StudentPaymentSchedules.save()
```

As an unrelated note, try to stick to PEP-8 naming principles (for example, variables and attributes must be in lower_case, only class names should be in CamelCase).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question sir, when i tried your answer, i get this error """"could not convert string to float: 'Upon Enrollment'""""

Comment: Please post the error message with full traceback too.

Comment: @kaito That seems to be caused by a typo in my answer (first line). See my updated answer.